# How does one change the default directory for R version 3.0.2 to a user specified directory in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: home-directory, r

I have just started using R and want to change the default directory from '/home' to a user specified one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set R's working directory by… changing the directory from where you run it from. So

```
cd /foo/bar
R
```

will start R in `/foo/bar`.

If you want to always start R in a particular directory, you can change the working directory in the application starter. To achieve that, you need to create a copy of the application starter `/usr/share/applications/R.desktop` in your user application starter directory `~/.local/share/applications/` and add a line starting with `Path=` and then insert the desired path name.

Short example for the command line:

```
echo "Path=/foo/bar" | cat /usr/share/applications/R.desktop - > ~/.local/share/applications/R.desktop
```